# Add border using css ::after

Tags: css

I am trying to add border which is inside the box, I need to use css after or before for this, how can I achieve this effect?

[image]

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Why don't you try border+outline properties?

Comment: Because I already have one border on the box.

Comment: So you want a border which is literally inside the box... Have you tried a `position: relative;` for the box and a `position: absolute;` for your ::after element? I mean, ::after is absolute from the div and you have a `top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` and its width/height hiwever want for the ::after element, with a border as desired (?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot of different ways you can achieve this effect, each with their own pros and cons (including how different properties affect document flow):

#### Outline with negative offset

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  outline: 2px solid darkred;
  outline-offset: -7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

#### Border and boxshadow

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid darkred;
  background-color: red;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

#### ::after

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.box::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  border: 2px solid darkred;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```